# Py2exe application error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

I have a python script, that should update the program (clear folder and copy new files into it). It works fine, but when I run *.exe file, generated from my script(with py2exe), it gave me an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "shutil.pyc", line 254, in rmtree
  File "shutil.pyc", line 252, in rmtree
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Project\\MyProg\\Prog\\app'
```

Here is my script:

```
app = 'C:\\Project\\MyProg\\Prog\\app'
update = 'C:\\Project\\MyProg\\Prog\\update'

os.system("taskkill /im file.exe /f")

time.sleep(2)

shutil.rmtree(app)
shutil.move(update, app)

newpath = update
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

with open('info', 'w') as f:
    f.write("updated")
subprocess.call(['C:\\Project\\MyProg\\Prog\\app\\file.exe'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you use py2exe on the file, close the script. If you don't see it running, go to your processes list on the task manager and make sure that your script isn't running. It will usually show up as simply python under the description. Just right click and select end process and then confirm.